# Facebook SDK - Display Fan Count on Website?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

### Situation

I've been using a plugin to display the fan count of my facebook-page on my wordpress-blog. A few months ago this plugin (and apparently all similar ones) stopped working. I suppose this happened because facebook changed their api.

Now I'm trying to do this manually.
Display the fan count of my facebook-page, nothing more. 
So no like-button next to it, no wrapper around it.

### Steps taken

I've included the facebook SDK like this:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.4'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

After that I did a quick test, to see if everything works with this:

```
<div
    class="fb-like"
    data-share="true"
    data-width="450"
    data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

This works as expected and a basic like-box is displayed.

### Problem

Now I've been through the docs to figure out how to just display the page-fan-count instead of the like box. Unfortunately this confused me more than it did help.

I understand that I **can't** just use something like this:

```
<div
    class="fb-fans"
    data-width="450">
</div>
```

The whole thing seems like such a simple thing to do, but I can't make sense of it all. Am I aproaching this completely wrong?

Thanks a lot for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not THAT simple, unfortunately. There is no plugin for that, so you have to create an App and use the Graph API to get the like count. But you do not need any authorization, you can just use an App Access Token. This would be the API call (use file_get_contents or CURL):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page.id?fields=name,likes&access_token=APP-ID|APP-SECRET
```

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#Reading

About Access Tokens in general:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

If you don´t want to create an App and deal with the Graph API, you can also just use a platform like SharedCount, they offer a good amount of free calls per day: http://www.sharedcount.com/

Comment: Thanks for the advice @luschn. I'll check it out. 
Do i actually need the script in the body then?

Comment: You should NOT have the app access token publically visible in the sourcees of your site...

Comment: yeah, it´s called app secret for a reason...because you need to keep it secret, never use it on the client.

Comment: i added another solution without the graph api in my answer, if you don´t want to create an app.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you can't use the standard like button, e.g. in *box_count* mode.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

If you specify the URL of your Facebook page as "URL to Like", then it show you the actual page likes:

[image]

Downside is that you can't really customize it, and that for larger numbers the counts are abbreviated...

Comment: Hey Tobi,
unfortunately I need JUST the blank number. So strange that this is so tricky. The count is visible to everyone anyway.

Comment: You should add that in your question... Then, you'll need to query the Graph API. It's very recommendable NOT to have the app access token visible to the public. Meaning that you'll need to create a simple backend proxy which will actually perform the call to the Graph API, and proxy the result to your frontend

Comment: _“unfortunately I need JUST the blank number”_ – why, who comes up with such strange requirements? I’d assume that you would actually want the number of fans to _grow_, and using the Like button is a perfectly simple way of achieving that. And look at it from a user perspective – a site displays me it’s current fan count, and I might even actually enjoy that site – but it offers me no possibility to become a fan myself right there and then – “wtf?” That hardly makes sense IMHO.